# Laravel - User registration plus stripe payment in try catch block

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Im using Laravel Cashier and also the authentication registration in one form and to process it all im using a try catch block.

```
try {
    // Process the credit card through Stripe
    // Register the user in the system
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Throw exception with error message
}
```

This works fine, but im wondering what would happen if the processing of the card worked, but the registering failed.

They would get charged and have no account.

How do you go about reversing actions taken if something fails?

Comment: Can't you just register the account in a disabled state and enable it later when the payment is successful? Wouldn't that also make it easier for them to retry payment if it has failed without registering again? To me it seems that registration is something you control, so validation etc should be done before you start the payment process.

Comment: First you have to register the user with inactive status, if the payment success update it in Active status

Answer (score 1):

You should use defferent try/catch for each process:

```
try {
  // Process the credit card through Stripe
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  // Throw exception with error message
}
```

And the second for register:

```
try {
  // Register the user in the system
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  // Throw exception with error message
}
```

This way you know exactly what failed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but even in this case, if the stripe process is successful and then the registration fails, it will still process the card and not sign the user up, wont it?

Comment: You can add statuses, like: `pre-registration`, `unpayed`, `payed`, `registered` etc. and change them each time you finish a step.

Answer (score 0):

You should try first register process because it's in our hand we can revert this if any thing goes wrong

```
try {
    // Register the user in the system  
    // Process the credit card through Stripe
    // If process fails throw custom exception
}catch( CustomException $e) {
   //revert the Register process
   //Throw exception
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Throw exception with error message
}
```